# JS: return promise from an async function without resolving the promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but asking just in case.

Let's say I have a bunch of functions that add to a query builder:

```
let query = User.query();
query = filterName(query, name);
query = filterLocation(query, location);
const users = await query;
```

This is fine. However, if I need one of these functions to be async (e.g. to fetch some data), I can't `await` the function because it'll resolve the whole query.

```
async function filterLocation(query, location) {
  const data = await ...;
  return query.where(...);
}

...

query = await filterLocation(query, location); // `query` is now resolved to a list of users, but I want it to remain a promise
```

Is there a way to make JS not resolve the promise returned by `filterLocation`? Do I have to wrap it in an object?

Comment: If you want just the promise, without waiting for it to resolve, do: `queryPromise = filterLocation(query, location)`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Promises start immediately, once you do `= User.query()` it's already started. It's too late to add stuff to it. What you need is something like `await query.exec()` on the last line, which would start the actual work. So yes, you have to wrap it.

Comment: await does not actually resolve anything, it (recursively) unwraps the promise to get its underlying value.

Comment: @georg I'm using knex, which allows me to use it the way in the question. I'm assuming they have `setTimeout(, 0)` to allow the query to be modified

Comment: @IAmDranged if you prefer "unwrap" over "resolve", then the question would be "can you return a promise from an async function without unwrapping the promise?"

Comment: I may be missing something but I don't see how a thenable could actually be returned by an await operation. By definition, any thenable resolved to by the awaited promise would in turn be unwrapped - until a non-thenable is produced.

Answer (score -4):

`await` can only be used inside an `async` function.

### Option 1: invoke an async anonymous function

```
...

(async function(){
   query = await filterLocation(query, location);
})();
```

### Option 2: use promise API (then)

```
...

filterLocation(query, location)
    .then(function (query){
       ...
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is all about.